# How to redirect SSO page (MSAL authentication) login.aspx (single page, not under master page) to another page Home.aspx (content in master page)?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm planning on to create 1 single page with SSO authentication (MSAL). Once it authenticates, it will redirect to another page which is content page in a master page.

Currently, I've tried to create login.html page with SSO (MSAL). It can authenticate and redirect to home.aspx page. But this is direct page, which is not content page under master page. What I'm planning to do is another way, from single page then redirect to home.aspx page (content under master page).

I expected it to flow like this:

1. User redirect to SSO page (login.aspx / login.html)
2. Once successful authenticate, the system will redirect the user to master page content (Home.aspx) with user info (username/email/etc.) that retrieve from MSAL.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here. Why can you not utilize the redirection url? The documentation for the MSAL.JS SSO can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso

From what it sounds like you just want the user to be authenticated and then redirect to a content page. You can do this by utilizing the redirect_url. Why is this insufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the MSAL.JS SSO can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso

From what it sounds like you just want the user to be authenticated and then redirect to a content page. You can do this by utilizing the redirect_url.